# Is a simple `continue` statement an acceptable alternative to nesting an entire for..in loop's body in the `if`?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop, hasownproperty

Typically, the solution to `for..in`'s notorious caveat is something along the lines of:

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        foo(); bar(); baz();
    }
}
```

I feel like it would be cleaner to just do:

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
}
```

The question is... Are they not ***functionally*** identical?

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste or style.

Comment: they are identical as much as the code logic is concerned (they may be different by performance or something else). I prefer the second version because you get rid of a layer of indentation

Comment: It is a matter of style and preference.  The first _positive_ example makes more sense to me.  _If this, then do that._ seems more meaningful than the negative _If not this, do nothing_

Comment: See - two comments come in within seconds of each other, having opposite viewpoints. Entirely up to preference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071762/unexpected-continue

Comment: I have a third option: extract a function from `if` body and name it nicely

Comment: @Pointy you misunderstood my question, man.

Comment: @GabiPurcaru If you'd have made an answer of that, I'd have **accepted** it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you can also think of it as _"unless this, move on to the next item."_

Comment: @adlwalrus no I didn't - it really is a matter of style; I perhaps should have mentioned that they do the same thing, but I figured you'd probably determined that empirically.

Comment: @Pointy: It is a matter of style as to which you use, because they are functionally equivalent, but the OP wants confirmation that they are functionally equivalent which is not a matter of style at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's exactly right.

Comment: @adlwalrus I said _may_ be different performance-wise. I won't post an  answer when I'm not sure I'm right

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ha, wish I could +1 your question-edit comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are functionally identical. Period.

As for the matter of style, Douglas and his JSLint say: don't use `continue`:

> > Avoid use of the continue statement. It tends to obscure the control flow of the function.

See http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html and search for "continue"

Comment: Jesus christ, I hate crockford and his fearmongering.

Comment: Indeed. It obscures the control flow of the function only for those incapable of basic reading. Which, admittedly, covers a big chunk of the JS userbase...

Comment: @adlwalrus: Crockford also seems to contradict Douglas on var declarations and spacing before the brackets in function declarations  `function foo() {...}` versus `function bar () {...}`, to name a few.

I think it really comes down to personal preference in these cases.

(http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations)

Comment: @Cerbrus There's no contradiction. Spacing before brackets, according to JSLint, is encouraged when the function literal is anonymous, such as `function () {}`. The reasoning behind this is quite solid and deserves a quote: "If the space is omitted, then it can appear that the *function's name is* **function**, which is an incorrect reading." I would also like to note, that this discussion went a bit outside of the scope of the question. Let's stop it at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are functionally identical.

---

I'd say the continue-less example is a little more semantic, though.

In the first example, you aren't negating the bool in your if, so, you have a typical
`if(property){"Execute the rest of this loop"}`
instead of
`if(not property){"Do not execute the rest of this loop"`}