# JSLint error: Expected 'ignore' and instead saw 'ex'

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, jslint

I use JSLint all the time, but just today, I came across an error that I've never seen before. With the following code, I got the error shown below:

```
try {

  document.execCommand('BackgroundImageCache', false, true);

} catch (ex) {}
```

Error:

```
Expected 'ignore' and instead saw 'ex'.
} catch (ex) {}
```

So I changed my code to the following, and the error went away:

```
try {

  document.execCommand('BackgroundImageCache', false, true);

} catch (ignore) {}
```

I can't find any explanation on the Internet regarding why this would fix the error. Does anyone know what's up or why this fixed the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you're right -- jslint didn't used to complain like this.  Instead, it told you that you needed to do something with `ex`, right?  I'll check github to see and edit this later.  **EDIT**: Great catch [by you]!  Crockford, JSLint's author, [added this on April 29th of this year](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/a16c7aede875da8c4d42b3ab9d7d892718a20ca0) around line 3444.  And he uses empty `catch` blocks in jslint's source, so I guess he has to give us the kludge too.  ;^)

JSLint wants you to kludge empty `catch` blocks with `ignore` as the variable name so that it's obvious to people reading your code that you **intentionally meant** not to do anything in your `catch` block.  As Crockford [says elsewhere](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), he feels that, "It is difficult to write correct programs while using idioms that are hard to distinguish from obvious errors."

**1.) `ex` used (okay)**

So (as I'm guessing you know) if you write this code and *do something* with `ex`, jslint doesn't complain.

```
/*jslint browser: true, white:true, sloppy:true*/

var spam;

try {
    spam = "spam";
} catch (ex) {
    window.alert(ex);
}
```

**2.) `ex` unused means `ignore` (okay too)**

So if you *mean* not to do anything with `ex`, he wants the code to tell folks you didn't screw up by leaving your `ex` equivalent in there by naming that variable `ignore`.

```
/*jslint browser: true, white:true, sloppy:true*/

var spam;

try {
    spam = "spam";
} catch (ignore) {
}
```

**3.) `ignore` used (error!)**

So, in typical Crockfordian fashion, you now *can't* use `ignore` and actually do something in the `catch` block!

```
/*jslint browser: true, white:true, sloppy:true*/

var spam;

try {
    spam = "spam";
} catch (ignore) {
    window.alert(ignore);
}
```

That gives

> Unexpected 'ignore'. `} catch (ignore) {`

Just another hyper-explicit "don't make code that looks like an error" move by Crockford.

(Aside: Might be fun to take a look at [Why are empty catch blocks a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea) while you're on the subject.  Honestly, though `ignore` is probably a useful convention, based on that discussion (I mean, it includes Skeet arguing against empty `catch` blocks!), I'm a little surprised Crockford allows the `ignore` kludge, as the above link has arguments that feel a lot like his for calling some regular expressions "unsafe".)

Comment: Wow! Great find, and great answer! Thanks a lot. I was honestly wondering if JSLint had been changed along the lines of what you mentioned or not, but I hadn't used a try-catch statement in so long, I wasn't sure. Thanks again for that great answer and that great link.